# Tranwrd just one letter in SAS

Tags: sas

How can i quote just one letter in sas?

```
%sysfunc(tranwrd(%quote(&string),%quote(T),%quote('Test')));
```

The Problem is, when the string has a 'T' and 'TR' that both get tranwrd to 'Test'

Comment: Show more code, such as %LET statements for assigning `string` and the `sysfunc` result.

Comment: For each input, what do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

SAS Macro variables are always character.  The arguments to macro functions are always character and generally won't require an extra layer of macro macro quoting, and definitely won't if the arguments are to be as literals.

Did you try this first ?

```
%let string = STACKOVERFLOW;
%let string_tweaked = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&string),T,Test);
%put NOTE: string_tweaked = &string_tweaked;
```

Do the macro values contain embedded single quotes ?

```
%let string = %str(S%'T%'ACKOVERFLOW);
%let string_tweaked = %qsysfunc(tranwrd(&string,'T','Test'));
%put NOTE: string_tweaked = &string_tweaked;
```

The second code sample is analogous to the following DATA step code (whose scope is different than that of the MACRO environment).  DATA step string values are explicitly quoted, with either double quote (`"`) or single quote (`'`)

```
data _null_;
  string = "S'T'ACKOVERFLOW";
  string_tweaked = tranwrd(string,"'T'","'Test'");
  put "NOTE: " string_tweaked=;
run;
```

Comment: I get the letters or strings from a prompt and save it to the variable. That works fine, i can get a 'T' or 'AR' or 'TR', 'A' and so on... if i tranwrd the 'TR' to 'Test' it works, but if i tranwrd just the letter 'T' than 'T' > 'Test' and 'TR' > 'Test'R.